# Calculate confidence interval for each row in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, confidence-interval

I have a pandas `dataframe` where each column is a prediction of a time series and would like to calculate a mean and the confidence interval around it so I can plot it. For now I am looping on each row, calculating the *mean, min, *and* max*, then plotting the *mean* with *fill_between(min,max)*, but I don't think that is the correct way to do it. The `dataframe` would look like:

| Pred1 | Pred2 | Pred3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | x1 | x1 |
| x2 | x2 | x2 |
| x3 | x3 | x3 |

Except it would be larger. Around 50 columns and 300 rows. Any idea of how I can do this efficiently? Have to do it on many similar tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can try with `mean`, `min` and `max` along the columns (axis=1)

```
ax = df.mean(axis=1).plot()
ax.fill_between(df.index, df.min(axis=1), df.max(axis=1), alpha=0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if I understand confidence interval correctly though. I am kind of doing it how you answered, but using the min and max feels wrong. Seems very affected by outliers, so thought it might be another way.

Comment: @sjokkopudd if you have outliers, you could consider to use quantile like instead of `df.min(axis=1)` you can do `df.quantile(0.1, axis=1)`, replace by any value from 0 to 0.5 instead of min and 0.5 to 1. for max  :) my answer was based on your explanation of fill_between thinking ot was exactely your expected output

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for

Comment: @sjokkopudd note that if your rows are independent, hence do not need to be plot as a line really, you can also have a look at `df.T.boxplot()` and check the documentation to see what is really plotted